# How to prevent PHP Code Execution Vulnerability on a site

Tags: php, mongodb

So I faced a problem that someone is trying to execute a php using a url?
For example.
http://example.com/search.php?keyword=${@print(md5(123456789))}

on what I read This will allows an attacker to inject custom code into the server side scripting engine. This vulnerability occurs when an attacker can control all or part of an input string that is fed into an eval() function call. Eval will execute the argument as code. an impact of this An attacker can execute any PHP code on your server.

I'm using mongoDB btw. I would love to someone to help me out to prevent this from any inputs.
Thanks in advance

Comment: afaik, you can't prevent people from trying that, but you can easily avoid any harm with the correct protections. That attempt you posted, unless you're using eval() on an unfiltered input, is innocuos

Comment: There is an eval function on my script.I'm using mongodb. I have a custom javascript code on that to handle the queries. So I'm pretty sure its getting in there. What would be the 'protections' you are talking about?

Comment: On what are you using the php `eval()`? Please add that code,so we can help you better in spotting a vulnerability.

Comment: See this question. May be it will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956001/security-concerns-while-using-mongodb-php-driver

Comment: It would be a dumb mistake to EVER use unsanitised input to determine the behaviour of your application, especially through eval. You'd have to make that mistake, PHP won't

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're referring to using PHP's `eval()` or MongoDB's [`eval`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) command (also invoked by [`MongoDB::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php)). If it's the latter, you have several ways of passing PHP values into your JavaScript while still avoiding the need to concatenate it in the JS code (e.g. as a variable assignment)

The `eval` command takes an `args` option, which allows you to provide arguments to the evaluated function. For the `MongoDB::execute()` command wrapper, this would be the second argument. If you are defining your JS functions with [MongoCode](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocode.construct.php) objects, which you should, you can also use the `scope` constructor argument to bind PHP values to variables in the JS context. Much like the `args` option for `eval`, PHP values here will be serialized to BSON and then made available to the JavaScript function. Beyond booleans, numbers, and strings, you can also pass in arrays, objects (real objects or associative arrays), and functions (by wrapping strings in MongoCode objects).

The following script should demonstrate how various PHP values may be passed to each calling method:

```
$m = new MongoClient();

$values = [
    true,
    1.5,
    'foo',
    [1,2,3],
    (object) ['a' => 1],
    new MongoCode('function() {}'),
];

foreach ($values as $value) {
    $type = is_object($value) ? get_class($value) : gettype($value);
    printf("\nTesting PHP type: %s\n", $type);

    $rs = $m->test->command([
        'eval' => 'function(a){ return Array.isArray(a) ? "array" : typeof a; }',
        'args' => [$value],
    ]);

    printf("MongoDB::command() with code string and args: %s\n", $rs['retval']);

    $rs = $m->test->execute(
        new MongoCode('function(a){ return Array.isArray(a) ? "array" : typeof a; }'),
        [$value]
    );

    printf("MongoDB::execute() with MongoCode and args: %s\n", $rs['retval']);

    $rs = $m->test->execute(
        'function(a){ return Array.isArray(a) ? "array" : typeof a; }',
        [$value]
    );

    printf("MongoDB::execute() with code string and args: %s\n", $rs['retval']);

    $rs = $m->test->execute(
        new MongoCode('function(){ return Array.isArray(b) ? "array" : typeof b; }', ['b' => $value])
    );

    printf("MongoDB::execute() with MongoCode scope: %s\n", $rs['retval']);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

you have to validate every input data from user.

You can use mysql_real_escape_string function to escape special characters,

and while coming to search functionality before directly searching with the keyword , first check whether the entered keyword is matching minimum requirement, like you are going to search data of integer values, but the entered value is a text, So in this case instead of searching directly it is better to validate entered data.

And anyway we can't say a site is 100% secure from vulnerability, we have to reduce the % of vulnerability.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is pretty useless with MongoDB, it's no even an SQL database. Also, validating is different from _escaping_ , wich is what should be done